# Json error at using Google Translate library in Python

Tags: python, json

I am working on a project in Python and I was using googletrans library to translate from one language to another. 5 mins ago, the program was working, but now I get a json error... I also tried a simple translation to see where lies the problem. I attached the printscreen here. https://snipboard.io/DL9soX.jpg

Simple demo code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate('Hello')
```

Comment: The error might be related to the characters that you are giving it. Try translating some simple text like "hello" and see if the error persists.

Comment: (1). Please post the code, don't post picture. (2). I tried the code in official repo (https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans) and it works fine. As @dnorhoj said, try testing with simpler stuff first.

Comment: @dnorhoj it is the same error no matter what I give it to translate: https://snipboard.io/c0oilp.jpg

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj I have updated the description.

Comment: Huh that's so weird it works fine for me.

Comment: @dnorhoj that's the problem. It used to work fine for me too moments ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Googletrans 2.3.0 documentation](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> **Note on library usage**
>
> - Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API **does not guarantee that the library would work properly at all times**. (so please use this library if you don’t care about stability.)
> - If you want to use a stable API, I highly recommend you to use Google’s official translate API.
> - If you get HTTP 5xx error or errors like #6, it’s probably because Google has banned your client IP address.

Comment: But also: "Googletrans is a free and unlimited python library"...